# How to transform a directory of git repositories to one repository containing submodules?

Tags: git

Today, I have a directory containing several git repositories. Up to now, I could live with it because the repositories were quite distinct and unrelated. But now, I would like to make a "distribution" (not a linux one...) of these repositories with specific commits.

The natural solution feels to transform these repos to submodules, and have the parent directory as a "parent / main repo".

But is there any way to do this automatically, rather than adding submodules one by one by hand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there any way to do this automatically, rather than adding submodules one by one by hand?

Write a bit of script to loop, adding submodules one by one:

```
git init  # you can do this by hand, it's just the one init
```

then the loop:

```
for dir in <list>; do git submodule add $dir; done
```

Your superproject is now ready for its first commit.  As [hl037_ noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573855/how-to-transform-a-directory-of-git-repositories-to-one-repository-containing-su/63583987?noredirect=1#comment112735297_63583987), a:

```
git submodule absorbgitdirs
```

is probably a reasonable thing to do at the end, and replacing `git submodule add path` with the longer `git submodule add -- repository path` [can help out in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573855/how-to-transform-a-directory-of-git-repositories-to-one-repository-containing-su/63583987?noredirect=1#comment112735297_63583987), especially when there's a remote repository name to use.

Comment: I didn't believe it but it actually work : a submodule doesn't have to be "absorbed" by the parent repo, its .git dirrectory can live inside the submodule. To complete your answer, may be you could add a word about `git submodule absorbgitdirs` that permit to "absorb" the submodule .git directory and being in exactely the same situation as if the submodule had been created from the super project.

Comment: Note also for the command `git submodule add`, if the submodule had a remote repo, you should instead use `git submodule add $remote -- $dir` which work with nested directories.

Comment: @hl037_ The un-absorbed style is the old way but still supported, so yes, the absorbgitdirs is probably a good idea. I had not thought about (or ever tested) nested submodule directories here, though.

Comment: The aborbdir is completely optionnal, actually, I think I prefer the old way with the directory : less chance to mess up the submodule while doing stuff with the super project (e.g. : delete the .git to clean and recreate the repo after strange error message #TrueStory). For nested sub dirs, you must call with `git submodule add $remote_url -- $dir`

Comment: Hm, you're not supposed to need the `--` in between these, but on the other hand the submodule code has had various bugs and is being updated on an ongoing basis right now.